# How to Add Application StartUp Image in Android Mobile?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android app, which at the moment when it is loading the Aplication, I just have a black screen (until the app gets its footing). I want to display a full screen image when black screen appears on the Emulator/Android Mobile. Looking at other apps they have a company logo or cool image that pops up for a few seconds, can someone tell me how to do this please?

I use this code:

```java
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
    /**
     * The thread to process splash screen events
     */
    private Thread mSplashThread;    

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Splash screen view
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        final SplashScreen sPlashScreen = this;   

        // The thread to wait for splash screen events
        mSplashThread =  new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    synchronized(this){
                        // Wait given period of time or exit on touch
                        wait(3000);
                    }
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex){                    
                }

                finish();

                // Run next activity
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(sPlashScreen, HomePage.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        };

        mSplashThread.start();        
    }

    /**
     * Processes splash screen touch events
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt) {
        if(evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            synchronized(mSplashThread){
                mSplashThread.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Try to write ur code in onresume method instead of oncreate method.

Comment: http://mukeshyadav4u.blogspot.in/2012/08/android-splash-screen-example.html

Comment: Have you tried something like splash screen??

Comment: You should avoid a splash screen if possible

Answer (score 4):

For this you have to set Splash Screen... You can also set Splash screen like this:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
                Intent menu = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(menu);
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

It will set splash screen for just 3 seconds and then your Main class will be display... And XML for splash screen is like this:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/splash_screen">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

### **its called Splash Screen**

check this code:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    /**
     * The thread to process splash screen events
     */
    private Thread mSplashThread;    

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Splash screen view
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        final SplashScreen sPlashScreen = this;   

        // The thread to wait for splash screen events
        mSplashThread =  new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    synchronized(this){
                        // Wait given period of time or exit on touch
                        wait(5000);
                    }
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex){                    
                }

                finish();

                // Run next activity
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(sPlashScreen, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                stop();                    
            }
        };

        mSplashThread.start();        
    }

    /**
     * Processes splash screen touch events
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt)
    {
        if(evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            synchronized(mSplashThread){
                mSplashThread.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }    
}
```

yout layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:id="@+id/TheSplashLayout"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  >
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/SplashImageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"        
        android:src="@drawable/lnxins"        
        >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[check this tutorial for more detail](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113831/An-Advanced-Splash-Screen-for-Android-App)

Comment: :Thanks For Your Response.It's working,but when i opened the application,frst 1-2sec it shows black screen only.can you please explain how directly opening the splash screen window instead of black screen.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Manojbabu: there is no issue with your code. in your activity_splash_screen.xml image size if large. that why it take some time. change some difrrent xml and check code is working fast. so try to change image size